# URL redirections issue

Tags: .htaccess

I am rewriting my url rules in htaccess, and also use sefURL (SEO Friendly URL's). But there is one issue,

When I am going to link from my page it will generate SEO Friendly URL's but if i am going in write direct file name over there, then also I want to redirect on the same URL'

For example,

On my page I got generated URL link of `http://www.exampleskey.com/myfirsthtpage`
So using htaccess it will point my servers `myfirsthtpage.php` file

Now if I wrote URL like this `http://www.exampleskey.com/myfirsthtpage.php` so it will just show me up a same URL, but if any one write above URL one should be redirect to the `http://www.exampleskey.com/myfirsthtpage` from htaccess. Any one help me to do.

I also tried with 'RewriteCond'  but not getting proper results.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?/)?(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2 [R=302,L,NE]

# To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: Hello,
Thanks for this. But its not working.

Comment: This is tested and working code from my live website. You have to make sure this is placed in DOCUMENT_ROOT and you have no other rule or no other .htaccess

Comment: Also rather than **its not working** kind of comment you should provide details about the problem you have. What URL are you entering in your browser and what is location of this .htaccess file? What error you got?

Answer (score -1):

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^myfirsthtpage/?$ myfirsthtpage.php [L]
```

Copy paste this code

Comment: Thsnks bro. but it will not work. It will my URL points to php page, not remove my .php extension on run time.

Comment: just copy paste this code and visit http://www.exampleskey.com/myfirsthtpage and look at address bar after that. It is working damn cool.YOu also can manage it runtime. My complete user portal works on this rules.

Comment: Hello dude,
Thanks you. But you didnt read my question properly. I want to prevent users to use `.php` extension. you say write and hit `exampleskey.com/myfirsthtpage` URL, that is cool it was already works for me. bu i want if any one hit `exampleskey.com/myfirsthtpage.php`, then one should redirect to `exampleskey.com/myfirsthtpage`.